# Shift some of footnotes to the very end of the document, after the References

Tags: bibliographies, footnotes, document-classes

I am editing an article for the term paper purpose. I am adding some footnote in the document. But my hope is that some of the footnote will appear at the very end of the document, after the References (which is called by bibliographystyle).

This is a simple template.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{1}
Foo\footnote{footnote1}

\section{2}
Bar\footnote{footnote2}

\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

For example, in the above I have both footnote1 and footnote2. Is there a way to make the footnote1 appears on the same page of the paragraph/section, however, to also make the footnote2 appears after the References?

One should imagine the document is as long as 15 pages or so. So criteria for the footnote 1 and footnote 2 are very different.

Another possibility is to make the footnote2 appears just right before the References?

Comment: Are you aware of the endnotes package?

Comment: Do you want a mixture of footnotes at the bottom of page and at the end of the document?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68115/unique-counter-for-all-foot-side-and-end-notes

Comment: " Do you want a mixture of footnotes at the bottom of page and at the end of the document? – Przemysław Scherwentke 2 hours ago " --> Yes

Comment: Secondary footnotes are degraded to the very end of article.

Comment: For example, telling a side story in a footnote.

Comment: This should be covered by the `endnotes` package as suggested by @marmot. See its documentation [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/endnotes)